# How to update first NULL column if not exist in another column

Tags: php, mysql

I want to run a mysql query to search and update first null column from a table `levels` where the value of the `uid1`, `uid2`, `uid3`, `uid4` columns does not equal myUniqueID.

Here is a simplified version of my table with content:

```
mysql> select * from levels;
+----+--------------+--------------+----------------+-----------------+-----------------------------------------+
| level_id|        uid1    |      uid2      |      uid3      |      uid4      |      status    |      level     |
+----+--------------+--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|    1    | 576da2176b9867 | 57709be6486012 | 57709be6006055 | 57709be6486077 |     closed     |     level9     |
|    2    | 57709be6486012 | 577c132ed56645 | 57709be0000044 | 57709be6486033 |     closed     |     level5     |
|    3    | 577c132ed56645 | 577c1339f34e11 | 57709be6486002 | 57709be6486011 |     running    |     level3     |
|    4    | 577c1339f34e11 |     NULL       |      NULL      |      NULL      |     opened     |     level2     |
+----+--------------+--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Here is my query:

```
UPDATE `levels` set 
`uid1`=IF(`uid1` IS NULL, IF ('$myUniqueID' not in (`uid2`,`uid3`,`uid4`),'$myUniqueID', NULL ), `uid1`),
`uid2`=IF(`uid1` IS NULL, IF ('$myUniqueID' not in (`uid1`,`uid3`,`uid4`),'$myUniqueID', NULL ), `uid2`),
`uid3`=IF(`uid1` IS NULL, IF ('$myUniqueID' not in (`uid2`,`uid1`,`uid4`),'$myUniqueID', NULL ), `uid3`),
`uid4`=IF(`uid1` IS NULL, IF ('$myUniqueID' not in (`uid2`,`uid3`,`uid1`),'$myUniqueID', NULL ), `uid4`)
WHERE  levels.`status` ='opened'  and  levels.level = 'level2'
```

Assuming `$myUniqueID` the value is `11111111111`, this query will update column `uid2` of row 4 and set it in `11111111111`. LIKE THIS:

```
+----+--------------+--------------+----------------+-----------------+-----------------------------------------+
| level_id|        uid1    |      uid2      |      uid3      |      uid4      |      status    |      level     |
+----+--------------+--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|    1    | 576da2176b9867 | 57709be6486012 | 57709be6006055 | 57709be6486077 |     closed     |     level9     |
|    2    | 57709be6486012 | 577c132ed56645 | 57709be0000044 | 57709be6486033 |     closed     |     level5     |
|    3    | 577c132ed56645 | 577c1339f34e11 | 57709be6486002 | 57709be6486011 |     running    |     level3     |
|    4    | 577c1339f34e11 |  111111111111  |      NULL      |      NULL      |     opened     |     level2     |
+----+--------------+--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The problem is that the internal **IF** always returns the **FALSE**, so the table does not change.

**Question_1 :** Can anyone find a solution to this?

**Question_2 :** How do I tell when a MySQL UPDATE was successful versus actually updated data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're testing `uid1 IS NULL` in each of the assignments. It has to check if all the preceding columns are `NOT NULL` and itself `IS NULL`.

```
UPDATE `levels` set 
    `uid1`=IF(`uid1` IS NULL, IF ('$myUniqueID' not in (IFNULL(`uid2`, ''),IFNULL(`uid3`, ''),IFNULL(`uid4`, '')),'$myUniqueID', NULL ), `uid1`),
    `uid2`=IF(`uid1` IS NOT NULL AND `uid2` IS NULL, IF ('$myUniqueID' not in (`uid1`,IFNULL(`uid3`, ''),IFNULL(`uid4`, '')),'$myUniqueID', NULL ), `uid2`),
    `uid3`=IF(`uid1` IS NOT NULL AND `uid2` IS NOT NULL AND `uid3` IS NULL, IF ('$myUniqueID' not in (`uid2`, `uid1`,IFNULL(`uid4`, '')),'$myUniqueID', NULL ), `uid3`),
    `uid4`=IF(`uid1` IS NOT NULL AND `uid2` IS NOT NULL AND `uid3` IS NOT NULL AND `uid4` IS NULL, IF ('$myUniqueID' not in (`uid2`, `uid3`, `uid1`),'$myUniqueID', NULL ), `uid4`)
WHERE  levels.`status` ='opened'  and  levels.level = 'level2'
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dca7df/1)

Question 2: You can use `SELECT ROW_COUNT();` after the `UPDATE` query to find out how many rows were updated. If nothing was updated this will return `0`.

Comment: Your code is reasonably correct. But the table did not change

Comment: section `IF ('$myUniqueID' not in (uid1,uid3,uid4)` always return **FALSE**

Comment: Need to use `IFNULL()` in the `NOT IN` checks. Otherwise, the null values cause those checks to fail.

Comment: Thank you for answer. but how to ***SELECT * From*** updated row?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM levels WHERE '$myUniqueID' IN (uid1, uid2, uid3, uid4)`.

Comment: I know this. But the `'$myUniqueID'` may be found in several rows.

Comment: There's no built-in way to know which rows were just updated. You could do a `SELECT` query first to find the rows that fit the criteria to be updated.

Comment: I assumed from the name that `$myUniqueID` is unique, so all the rows that have it were the ones that were just updated.